# Trouble running Maven in the quickstart guide

Tags: daml

I am working through the [Digital Asset quickstart guide](https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html).  I am having trouble running:

```
mvn clean compile exec:java
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.373 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-13T17:22:14-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/50M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project daml-quickstart-java: Could not resolve dependencies for project quickstart:daml-quickstart-java:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.daml.ledger:bindings-java:jar:2.5.2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.daml.ledger:bindings-java:jar:2.5.2: Could not transfer artifact com.daml.ledger:bindings-java:pom:2.5.2 from/to bintray-digitalassetsdk-DigitalAssetSDK (https://digitalassetsdk.bintray.com/DigitalAssetSDK): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

How do I get authorization?

Answer (score 2):

To use the Java bindings you need to set up Maven to work with the Digital Asset Maven repository in Bintray.

- Log in to Bintray
- Open the Bintray repository main page
- Click on the **SET ME UP!** button and download the `settings.xml` file
- If you already have a `~/.m2/settings.xml`, integrate the downloaded file with
  it. Otherwise, copy the downloaded `settings.xml` file to `~/.m2/settings.xml`.
- Go to your Bintray profile page. Here you can get your Bintray username (`<name>@digitalassetsdk`, displayed below **Edit Your Profile**) and your Bintray API key, which you’ll need in the next step.
- In `settings.xml`, change the `username` and the `apikey` fields to your Bintray username and API key.

You can also find these instructions with direct Bintray links [in the documentation](https://docs.daml.com/packages/sdk-docs-installation/index.html#configure-maven-to-work-with-the-digital-asset-repository).